# Matlab converting library to model

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm working on a script to convert a Simulink library to a plain model, meaning it can be simulated, it does not auto-lock etc.

Is there a way to do this with code aside from basically copy-pasting every single block into a new model? And if it isn't, what is the most efficient way to do the "copy-paste".

I was not able to find any clues as how to approach this problem here, or on Google, or on the official documentation or on the MathWorks forum so I'm at a loss on how to proceed.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to convert a library to a model, but you can programmatically add library blocks to models like so:

```
sys = 'testModel';
new_system(sys);
open_system(sys);
add_block('Simulink/Sources/Sine Wave', [sys, '/MySineWave']);
save_system(sys);
close_system(sys);
sim(sys);
```

You could even use the [find_system](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/find_system.html) command to list all the blocks in a library and then loop through them all and create a new model for each using the above code.